# How can we use ASP.Net RegularExpressionValidator for multilanguage support?

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex

I am using a ASP.Net RegularExpressionValidator to validate.

Text Only

```
^(a-z|A-Z|0-9)*[^#$%^&*()\']*$
```

Alphanumeric Only

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9]*$
```

Numeric Only

```
^[0-9]*$
```

I need to use these expression to work fine with multilanguage (Japanese, Chinese etc..)

Answer (score 2):

Use [Unicode properties](http://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html#prop).

e.g.:

`\p{L}` any kind of letter from any language

`\d` a digit, in .net those character shorthand classes are Unicode based.

`\p{Nd}` a digit zero through nine in any script except ideographic scripts

`\p{N}` any kind of numeric character in any script. Would e.g. allow roman numbers like "VII"

Regarding your first expression: Ranges (the `a-z` part) can only be used inside of character classes. So the part `(a-z|A-Z|0-9)` matches literally either "a-z", "A-Z" or "0-9".

You could change your first expression to

```
^[\p{L}\d]*[^#$%^&*()\']*$
```

Your second could be

```
^[\p{L}\d]*$
```

or

```
^[\p{L}\p{Nd}]*$
```

and the last one

```
^\d*$
```

or

```
^\p{Nd}*$
```

Comment: It it my understanding that JScript, which the RegularExpressionValidator uses for client-side validation, does not support patterns such as `\p{L}`